# Regex: finding a number between a range with decimals

Tags: regex, numbers, range

I can not for the life of me get my head around this regex stuff after a few days of fiddling around I find myself seeking help from those wiser than I. Could any of you kind souls write me a line(s) that will find and match a number between `0.00` and `x.xx`? I do need the decimals however so hopefully this can be done.

I actually tried using

```
(\b|^)(0.00|0.01|0.02)(\b|$)
```

until `x.xx` and so forth but I couldn't fit the rest of it in because I need it to go into the 100.00+. Would anyone mind whipping something up real quick for me? : ) I would appreciate it more than you can imagine! Thanks very much for your time.

Ray.

**Edit:**
So i forgot to explain what I'm trying to achieve here, I'm using it in conjunction with a Chrome addon called Page Monitor (life saver folks try it out when you have time to kill!) which pings every time an a website updates, this also works for shares but I'm trying to make it only alert me when the price drops below a certain point eg `$4.99` per share, will `(\b|^)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})(\b|$)` and `([0-9]+.[0-9]+)` suffice?

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching strings.  If you want to match numbers as strings press ahead, if you want to match numbers as values, choose another tool.

Comment: wow...2 close votes saying a regex question is not about programming? i woulda agreed with "unclear what you're asking" but come on guys.. :/

Comment: Can you post your input and output data model, that will be helpful?

Comment: @ High performance Mark: hey mate, yea I realize this might not be the best tool but I'm afraid the addon I'm working with is pretty inflexible with only regex or "selector" whatever that is

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't this good enough: ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) ?

If you can give an example of input and what is the output you expect, it would be easier to write a regex.

Updated: $ sign is a reserved character in RegEx, it means end-of-line, so you need to use \$, if you plan on using it.

So your regex would be \$([0-9]+\.[0-9]+), this would capture your $4.99 and $5.10, etc, not just $4.99

Regexs in general are good at capturing data, less at analyzing it, but if you must, you can do this to determine when the price goes below $4.99 =>
\$(([0-3]\.[0-9]+)|(4\.[0-8][0-9])|(4\.9[0-8]))

It should be obvious that its a waste of resource :)

Comment: Okay sure sure, sorry should've done that in the first place. I will put this in the question.

Comment: I did escape, but it ate it :)

Comment: Hey thanks man : ) Sorry to make you hold my hand here but does this look right, then? 

(b\$)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|1[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|2[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|3[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|4[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|5[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|6[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|7[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|8[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|9[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|10[0-9]+\.[0-9]) (\b|$)

It doesn't look right does it : (

Comment: No that is wrong - use http://regexpal.com/ for testing, the regex you wrote will capture everything as "+" means one or more of the "item" before it, i.e. [0-9] (i.e.a any digit). You also wrote (b\$) what is that "b" ?

Comment: okay : P Ty, I will try again. PS: just so you know I'm in way over my head here, so at this stage I'm just trying different...things, more or less at random! Nonetheless, will get there! (eventually)

Comment: ooookay > : D how about THIS?! (\b)([0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(1[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(2[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(3[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(4[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(5[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(6[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(7[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(8[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})|(9[0-9]\.[0-9]{2})(\b)

Comment: No that aint right either T_T okay take 3

Comment: Again, Regex is for capturing data, not comparing values, if you want to capture anything below $4.99 use this Regex (which I already wrote): \$(([0-3]\\.[0-9]+)|(4\\.[0-8][0-9])|(4\\.9[0-8])) if you want to capture anything below $9.99 use this: \$(([0-8]\\.[0-9][0-9])|(9\\.[0-8][0-9])|(9\\.9[0-8]))

Answer (score 0):

Didn't provide enough info but this will match if the number is the entire value or if it is within a larger string and the number is not withing something else like "foo8.9bar".  This will match any 1 or more digit number on the left side of the decimal and exactly 2 numbers on the right side

`(\b|^)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})(\b|$)`

Answer (score 0):

(\b|^) and (\b|$) are redundant because \b implies ^ and $.

Answer (score 0):

this regex: (\d+\.\d{2}) should do it.

Comment: Hey Heto : P Appreciate the help bud, yea I just tried it in regexpal and sure enough it finds all the numbers but how do I set the limit so it only finds numbers below a the desired threshold?